# jshint expects the new 'prefix' for functions

Tags: javascript, jshint

`CSiginIn`, `CSignUp`, `CTryIt`, `CBlocks` are all functions declared as such

```
function CSignIn(){//stuff here}
```

yet JSHint says that I am missing the 'new' 'prefix'.  What can I do to fix this?

They are just functions inside the module pattern.  Also, it is asking me to remove semicolons I had placed at the end of the function which I have done.

```
var Control = ( function () 
{

    /**
     *Publik
     */

    var publik = function ( page )
    {
        // page 1 initialization

        if( page == 1 )
        {
            CSignIn();
            CSignUp();
            CTryIt();
            CBlocks();
        }
```

Function Example...

```
function CTryIt()
{
    // pull elements

    var tryit_button = document.getElementById( 'tryit_button' );

    // initialize access to Model

    tryit_button.addEventListener( "click", function( )
    { 
        new AjaxRequest().invoke( 'ajax_type=ControlTryIt', 
        function( server_response_text ) 
        { 
            new AjaxResponse( server_response_text, 'page_change' ); 
        } ); 

    }, false );
}
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

If `newcap` is enabled, JSHint expects functions starting with a capital letter to be constructors and therefore to be called with the `new` keyword.

**Solution**: Either disable this option or rename your functions.

From the [documentation](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#newcap):

> This option requires you to capitalize names of constructor functions. Capitalizing functions that are intended to be used with `new` operator is just a convention that helps programmers to visually distinguish constructor functions from other types of functions to help spot mistakes when using `this`.
>
> Not doing so won't break your code in any browsers or environments but it will be a bit harder to figure out—by reading the code—if the function was supposed to be used with or without `new`. And this is important because when the function that was intended to be used with `new` is used without it, `this` will point to the global object instead of a new object.
>
> ```
> function MyConstructor() {
>     console.log(this);
> }
>
> new MyConstructor(); // -> [MyConstructor]
> MyConstructor();     // -> [DOMWindow]
> ```

For a more in-depth understanding on how `this` works, read [Understanding JavaScript Function Invocation and "this"](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/) by Yehuda Katz.

Comment: O.K. I don't want to confuse others so I will likely loose the caps..thanks for the info.

Answer (score 6):

Felix Kling already gave you the correct answer. For completeness, I would note that `newcap` defaults to `true` (The documentation doesn't state it, but you can read it in the [source code](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/src/options.js)). This means that deleting the setting `newcap: true` in the JSHint options will not disable the warning: instead, you need to explicitly set `newcap: false`.