# Error : missing new prefix when invoking a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I am trying to create a function in `node.js`. The following is relevant code, it gives me error when i call function.

```
function ReplacePlaceholders() {
            return 'success';
          }      



  exports.sendMailMsg = function (templateName, receiverEmail, dataPlaceholders) {

        ReplacePlaceholders();
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you show here unless `ReplacePlaceholders()` is not in the same scope as `exports.sendMailMsg` or unless `exports` is not an object.  What specific error do you get?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In node.js, function names are camel cased, and should start with a lowercase character.  Starting a function with an uppercase character tells JSHint to consider the function a constructor rather than a method.

This is actually an error being generated by JSHint, but the code will run correctly.  [The option in JSHint](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#newcap), `newcap`, which causes this error is actually depreciated, and disabling it is recommended.

The relevant info as to why this option is even in JSHint:

> This option requires you to capitalize names of constructor functions. Capitalizing functions that are intended to be used with `new` operator is just a convention that helps programmers to visually distinguish constructor functions from other types of functions to help spot mistakes when using this.
>
> Not doing so won't break your code in any browsers or environments but it will be a bit harder to figure out—by reading the code—if the function was supposed to be used with or without `new`. And this is important because when the function that was intended to be used with new is used without it, `this` will point to the global object instead of a new object.

Comment: Thanks frnd...I wasted my half day for this simple thing...!

Comment: This is simply NOT true.  Javascript is case sensitive, but Javascript does NOT treat a function any differently if it starts with a capital letter or not - there's no special behavior assigned just because something starts with a capital letter.  There are style conventions that use capitalization a certain way, but those are purely style opinions on how to use the language.

Comment: node.js and it's associated linting will throw errors and not process the code correctly.  While it is true that it's mostly a style opinion, node.js expects you to conform to their style.  I should perhaps state more clearly this is node.js, not generic JavaScript

Comment: No, this code works fine in Node.js. Node.js does not force you to follow that convention. The error/warning message probably comes from JSHint, which may be configured in your text editor.

Answer (score 3):

The error message you mention is a JSHint error message, not a runtime error. There is a discussion of it here:

[jshint expects the new 'prefix' for functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668111/jshint-expects-the-new-prefix-for-functions)

JSHint expects functions that start with a capital letter to be object definitions. You can ignore the error, disable it in JSHint, or rename your function so that it starts with a lower-case letter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that might be, but that error suggests that doing `new ReplacePlaceholders();` might work. Though, you may want to consider something like the following:

```
function ReplacePlaceholders(templateName, receiverEmail, dataPlaceholders) {
  return 'success';
}

exports.sendMailMsg = ReplacePlaceholders;
```